# SQL Server query to get next nearest date from recurring events

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

This is my scenario. I have a table with `FirstMaintenanceEventDate` and some data repeating after certain days from `FirstMaintenanceEventDate`. What I need to find out through a SQL Server query is to get the nearest date of each row among them.

Ex: there is a data row `FirstMaintenanceEventDate` is last month and it will repeat after 40 days which is next month. Likewise there are a lot of events here. Some of them have `FirstMaintenanceEventDate` in the future. Out of all these items I need to get the nearest date for each row.

I could get the nearest date without considering repeating process.

This is my query

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM FIS_MaintenanceEventInstance
WHERE VehicleName = '600-GUR' 
  AND FirstMaintenanceEventDate >= GETDATE() 
ORDER BY FirstMaintenanceEventDate ASC
```

Need to update it to consider repeat events as I describe above. Probably something like this but this isn't correct.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM FIS_MaintenanceEventInstance
WHERE 
    VehicleName = '600-GUR' 
    AND FirstMaintenanceEventDate >= GETDATE()
    AND CASE 
           WHEN FirstMaintenanceEventDate < GETDATE() 
              THEN (Getdate() + RecurringDays) 
        END 
ORDER BY FirstMaintenanceEventDate ASC
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

NOTE: If you need more information please let me now.

**EDITED**
I have tried follow query as Jatin Patel suggested in his answer below.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *, 
    CASE WHEN  FirstMaintenanceEventDate < GETDATE() THEN DateAdd(day,RecurringDays,FirstMaintenanceEventDate)
     ELSE FirstMaintenanceEventDate END AS MaintenanceEventDate
FROM FIS_MaintenanceEventInstance
WHERE VehicleName ='600-GUR' 
ORDER BY MaintenanceEventDate ASC
```

This is not working as expected. After calculate the repeat date (here it's MaintenanceEventDate) also should consider when get the nearest date. According to this query it is calculate repeated date (MaintenanceEventDate) if it is in past and return it without check with other dates in the table.

Comment: Now are you talking about `mysql` or `mssql`? You mix both names...

Comment: If you have `FirstMaintenanceEventDate >= GETDATE()` in your `WHERE` clause, then the expression in the `CASE`: `WHEN FirstMaintenanceEventDate < GETDATE()` can ***never*** be true - so this whole `CASE` expression is useless and won't help in any way.....

Comment: @arkascha I'm sorry If I confused you. This is mssql.

Comment: @marc_s I know  second query isn't correct. So do you have any idea to get this done or else do I have to use separate calculation to find out repeating date without using the same query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT TOP 1 *, 
    CASE WHEN  FirstMaintenanceEventDate < GETDATE() THEN (Getdate()+RecurringDays) ELSE FirstMaintenanceEventDate END AS MaintenanceEventDate
FROM FIS_MaintenanceEventInstance
WHERE VehicleName ='600-GUR' 
ORDER BY MaintenanceEventDate ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is near to my requirement But here "(Getdate()+RecurringDays)" should change to "(FirstMaintenanceEventDate+RecurringDays)". When I tried it, I got an error as "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int". "FirstMaintenanceEventDate" is date type. Do you have any idea to corrent it?

Comment: I could correct it as "SELECT TOP 1 *, 
    CASE WHEN  FirstMaintenanceEventDate < GETDATE() THEN DateAdd(day,RecurringDays,FirstMaintenanceEventDate)
     ELSE FirstMaintenanceEventDate END AS MaintenanceEventDate
FROM FIS_MaintenanceEventInstance
WHERE VehicleName ='600-GUR' 
ORDER BY MaintenanceEventDate ASC". But this is not I'm looking. Here when calculate to find the nearest date, that repeat date also should conside. I mean "MaintenanceEventDate" in this query should also consider. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I am not sure I understood it correctly, but if you mean to say that the FirstMaintenanceEventDate date is entered only once for an Event and you need to calculate its repeating occurrence up to near future date than replace this "DateAdd(day,RecurringDays,FirstMaintenanceEventDate)" with 
"DateAdd(day,RecurringDays*(DateDiff(day,FirstMaintenanceEventDate,GetDate())/RecurringDays + 1) ,FirstMaintenanceEventDate)"